# Unable to access ColdFusion webservice from C# class

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion

I have to use a ColdFusion webservice in my project. I have
added the service reference in my project and it was successfully loaded, but
service is not accessible in my web application.

What I have done is let's say I have a url `http://www.server/service.cfc?wsdl` - I have added the above service reference and given the service reference name as `MyServiceReference`.

When I am accessing `MyServiceReference` in my class file it is not accessible.

Comment: What technology are you trying to call the service with? What lines of code are you using to call your service? What happens when you go to the wsdl url in a browser? What code do you have inside your cfc? 

You need to provide a lot more detail in your question otherwise you are essentially asking "how long is a piece of string?"

Comment: Stephen, thanku for your interest.I am using ASP.net(c#) to call this service.I have metioned in the post that I have given the reference name as "MyServiceReference", so I am using this same name in my class file to access the service.

Comment: .Net clients don't tend to like the default ColdFusion WSDLs. You may  need to change the style attribute of the cfcomponent tag from rpc to document. You may also need to edit the WSDL. access the cfc from the ?WSDL url and save it somewhere. Check for any type="any" attributes an change them to type="String". You then use the 'wsdlfile' attribute of cfcomponent. If you can't change the ColdFusion code at all, you may be able to save and tweak the wsdl, generate your classes from the local wsdl, then change the endpoint you use the be the real ColdFusion one.

Comment: added .net tag to broaden audience.  @shanky is using .net to access cf webservice.

Comment: Shanky, you've ignored most of Stephen's requests. Post the C# code you're using; Post _exact_ error message you're receiving; Verify that the WSDL is displaying correctly; etc...

Comment: @Stephen,I have the service url, what I have done is that I have added it as a web reference in my web application, and given the reference name as "MyServiceReference". After, adding this reference I must be able to get the referenced name in my app, but I am not able get this name resolved there.I think, this will clarify some of Stepehens doubts.

Comment: @Shanky - Have you followed barnyr's advice above?  CF puts out a WSDL that the Visual Studio automated Web Reference consumer doesn't handle well, specifically look at barnyr's suggestions for type "any".  I now tend to write my own interconnect classes for CF calls.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue this week when consuming a Coldfusion webservice. To solve it I suggest you can:

#### 1. Consume the WS using old 'Add Web Reference' (like .NET 2.0) instead of using 'Add Service Reference'

In my case, the problem was the webservice's methods were generated with return void and they hadn't had parameters, but when I added the service using this technique the proxies were correctly generated. This [post](http://edanan.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/add-coldfusion-web-service-using-web-reference-instead-of-service-reference/) has helped me.

#### 2. Try using WSDL.exe from Visual Studio Developer Command Tools to see if there is an error with service description

If there is maybe you will not be able to generate proxies correctly and you should ask developers to correct the service.
The tool I mentioned can be found at 'Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Visual Studio Tools\Developer Command Prompt for VS2012' (also for VS2010).
In my case I've seen the following error:

> "This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.R2706:
> A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST use the value of "literal" for the use attribute in all soapbind:body, soapbind:fault, soapbind:header and soapbind:headerfault elements."

Comment: +1 This was my problem exactly.  Point 1 worked for me.  Adding a service reference would always give me parameterless methods in the proxy.